# How to count total number of a specific keyword on a webpage using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Suppose on google home page i searched A KEYWORD say "selenium" with the help of webdriver and now i want to count total number ofkeyword selenium starting with capital S (Selenium) and with small s (selenium).please help

Comment: Start by grabbing the source, narrow it down to actual text and then filter based on your keyword.

Comment: downvote: no effort made. please provide what you have tried so far, what issues you are experiencing, etc

Comment: That question just arise in a critical scenario so typed here for solution.one solution just helped me move towards for stability in code..

Comment: @ManmohanSingh please share the code if you found the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try like this (also suggested by @bmcculley )

1.After you have searched a keyword.
                                                                                                2.Try to find the word in question by looking at the source ,you will find a  definite pattern in the source code.
3.Now take that pattern in a list like below

```
List<WebElement> keyword = driver.findElements(By.xpath(yourXpath));
```

This will iterate over each and every pattern that you have identified over the web page then 
`System.out.println("Size of Text with Capital " + keyword.size());`this will print the size of the word (do same thing for the small keyword)